# Telerik RadAjaxManager still postbacks

Tags: asp.net, ajax, postback, telerik

I've the following code in my page:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="ajax_manager" runat="server" 
    DefaultLoadingPanelID="ajax_panel">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="mygrid">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="mygrid" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>            
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

The "mygrid" above is a RadGrid, with grouping and paging. The purpose is to expand the groups or change the page "without" postbacks (I think that should be the objective of the RadAjaxManager, anyway).

But after all, the components still postbacks... =(

Some hint of what could it be?

Regards!

Comment: Weird, pasted code is correct. Any javascript error on the page?

Comment: The Console Error show no errors... =( It works like the page hasn't any RadAjaxManager. I've read about this in http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajxcontrolstillpostbacks.html, but didn't resolve either... Maybe it has to do with master page or something like...

Comment: Telerik really does make an awesome toolset. I've been stuck occasionally on something like this and it can be a real time consuming nightmare.

It would help if you posted your entire page so that we can see it all in full context.

Comment: RadAjaxManager did not prevent controls from doing postbacks.
Your question need to be edited with the code of your page in order to be constructive.

Answer (score 6):

Try this one :

```
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting>
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadAjaxPanel1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" IsSticky="False"
    Skin="Web20" Style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    EnableSkinTransparency="true" Transparency="0">
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
**YOUR GRID**
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

Comment: It still has some issues, but at least some part works, only the first event (grouping, sorting, etc ..) makes a postback, but from that point forward works fine. Thanks !, Even if it wasn't my question

Answer (score 1):

Try setting this property

```
var grid = new RadGrid();
...
grid.MasterTableView.GroupLoadMode = GridGroupLoadMode.Client;
```